# how to get repeated integer value from string specific operators in python

Tags: python

I have a string value that contains numbers symbols and character.
The string is :

```
"1=value.2=value.4=value + 3=value.4=value+5=value"
```

How to find how many repeated key value in whole string and also find repeated key values separated by + operator?

Is there a better way than splitting the string?

Comment: What is the key and what is the value?

Comment: can you post the desired output?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I believe he wants to split his string on every `.` and `+` and get the key value pairs as one string separated by the `=` sign. eg: `1=value`, `4=value`, etc...

Comment: Have you tried simply counting the number of `.` and `+` in the string?

Comment: You may want to read [ask] and [mcve], and re-word your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the another way . If my understanding is right.

```
import re
s = "1=value.2=value.4=value + 3=value.4=value+5=value"
# finding the all value like '1=value' as a list
new_dict_list = re.findall(r'\d+=?\w+', s)
# declaring dict for creating key value dict
new_dict={}
# declare a dict for creating key counting repetition
count_dict_key = {}
for ls in new_dict_list:
    # split the list element for finding and storing key and value
    split_value = ls.split('=')
    key = split_value[0]
    value = split_value[1]
    # checking the repetition key
    if split_value[0] in new_dict:
        count_dict_key[key] = ''.join(new_dict_list).count(key)
    else:
        new_dict[split_value[0]]=value
        count_dict_key[split_value[0]]=1

print("printing new dictionary....\n",new_dict)
print("counting key...\n",count_dict_key)
```

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a better way than splitting the string?

Not really. You can use [`re.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split) to split the string on every `.` and `+` character. And you can use `len()` to then get the length of the resulting list which corresponds to the number of "key, value" pairs:

```
>>> from re import split
>>> string = "1=value.2=value.4=value + 3=value.4=value+5=value"
>>> kv_pairs = re.split('\.|\+', string)
>>> kv_pairs
['1=value', '2=value', '4=value ', ' 3=value', '4=value', '5=value']
>>> len(kv_pairs) # number of key, value pairs
6
>>>
```

If you want to count repeated key, value pairs, you can use `collections.Counter()`. Note however, that in your example there are no repeated key, value pairs:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> {k: v for k, v in dict(Counter(kv_pairs)).items() if v > 1}
{}
>>>
```

If you also want to include the separators, you can wrap the regex in parenthesis you form a capture group:

```
>>> kv_pairs = re.split('(\.|\+)', string)
>>> kv_pairs
['1=value', '.', '2=value', '.', '4=value ', '+', ' 3=value', '.', '4=value', '+', '5=value']
>>>
```

Comment: Didn't he want to count repeated key/value pairs as well? (could you just compare length of a Set of the data to length of the list)